# how to write a file so that it does not have commas and remains in same format in R

Tags: r, write.table

I am reading file in R:

```
data <- read.delim ("file.fas", header=TRUE, sep="\t" )
```

However, after I have done some manipulations to the data, the output format is not same. It now contains commas "," like this all over.

```
write.table(x= data, file = "file_1.fas")
```

How can I avoid this? Maybe I should use some different function to write a file?

Comment: The manual page, `?write.table`, documents the arguments that control how the file is written. You can control separators (tabs, commas, etc) and quotation marks around fields.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. but there is one more problem now its automatically creating row numbers now, 1,2,3,4 etc which are not required and I can't see any argument for this in documentation of write.table. you have any suggestions

Comment: Look at the `row.names=` argument.